# How to combine 2 functions to find equation of a line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

[image]

I want to find the equation of a line that has equation $y\ =\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos\left(x\right)}}+1$ at x > 0, and has equation $y\ =\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos\left(x\right)}}+3$ at x<0. The line looks to be of the form $y = x^3 + 2$, but is there any way to find this other than trial and error of parameters?

Comment: You said: "I know the line will be of the form $y=x^3 +2$ ..."  - how did you get this? It's quite different from the other expressions.

Comment: So if you want a single expression that will exactly match $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}} + 1$ and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}+3$, you could just use the sign function to determine the sign of $x$ ...

Comment: @MattiP. I said that because it looks visually similar to what I want to achieve - I don't know that it'll be exactly like that - I'll update the question. Does using the sgn function create a single equation for the line?

Comment: I think you're making this too complicated for yourself. You could simply use the function
$$
f(x) = \frac{sign(x)}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}} + 2 -sign(x)
$$
where $sign(x)$ is the sign of $x$ (1 for positive, -1 for negative). This gives exactly the thing you want.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks, that worked fine.